# Get fast functor from text of expression in Python (faster than eval)

Tags: python, performance, exec, eval, functor

I have some trouble with performance.
I need to execute expression written in Python syntax in string.

```
def FindOccurences( data, condition, left, right ):
    result = []
    func = eval( u"lambda data, i : " + condition )
    for i in range(left, right):
        if(func( data, i ) == True ):
            result.append( i )
    return result
```

This code works but it it ~3-4 times slower than if

```
if(func( data, i ) == True):
    result.append( i )
```

will be replaced with:

```
if( *condition* ):
    result.append( i )
```

But I don't wanna generate python script from template for each condition.

Is there any way to increase performance of first variant of the script?

PS there is no need to care about safety, this functionality will be used by people, who included in project

Comment: How about pass `lambda data, i: ...` instead of a string condition?

Comment: really eval with no saftey, try this as condition. __import__('os').getcwd() or __import__('os').listdir('.')

Comment: I'm writing some small automatization for tests. Other people (they know basics of Python syntax) can write simple strings with conditions (they all included in project, no need for safety) and these strings must be executed and checked for each element in data. I'm not good Pythonist. Probably, I don't know a good way to do check condition, which is written in string.

Comment: Letting users to eval some arbitrary code is a serious security issue. If you are doing it only for testing purposes, I'd recommend you using [BDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior-driven_development) via [lettuce](http://pythonhosted.org//lettuce/). That way, you will define the types of action you want to be execute and users with no programming experience (or with basic Python syntax knowledge) can target those tests via natural language.

Comment: @falsetru can you, please, spare me the details. I'm getting string condition from files (this file probably contains more than one condition, but there is a reason to check each of them separately), and how can I construct lambda?

Comment: @avenet this functionality will be allowed only to few testers in project. They all know Python. There is no need to care about safety or giving them some natural language interface. But, thanks for advice, I'll take a note of this tool.

Comment: It looks like the only difference between your two cases is the function call.  If that's true, then it can't be much of a difference.  Are you sure the "3-4x" matters?  I would imagine it's a small percentage of the total time you're spending in tests.  There must be something I'm not understanding.

Comment: BTW: you don't need the `== True` comparison. Just use `if func(data, i):`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). That way you won't have to load the `list.append` function into memory and it can boost your script, for not having to do a lot of appends, so check [this article](http://blog.cdleary.com/2010/04/efficiency-of-list-comprehensions/) for a comparison. The code using list comprehensions can be written this way:

```
def FindOccurences(data, condition, left, right):
    func = eval( u"lambda data, i : " + condition)
    return [i for i in range(left, right) if func(data, i)]
```

I'd also return an iterator over the `indexes` which are the result of the function, like this:

```
def FindOccurences(data, condition, left, right):
    func = eval( u"lambda data, i : " + condition)
    return (i for i in range(left, right) if func(data, i))
```

That way, we can take the first three results of FindOcurrences method without getting the list with all of the results, sure we can do it by tweaking the left, right, but this way is more an on-demand approach:

```
from itertools import islice

results = islice(FindOccurrences(mydata, condition_str, 0, 100)

for item in result:
     print item
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call eval on just the condition which should be much faster:

```
func = (lambda data, i :  eval(condition) )


Using  a simple example:

In [28]: condition = "i > 10"

In [29]: timeit func = (lambda i:  eval(condition))
10000000 loops, best of 3: 62.8 ns per loop

In [30]: timeit eval( u"lambda data, i : " + condition )
100000 loops, best of 3: 13.9 µs per loop
```

Put it in a list comp and `if func(data, i)` is the same as `if func(data, i) == True`, you also don't need parens in  your if statements and use lowercase for function names.

```
def find_occurrences( data, condition, left, right ):
    func = eval(lambda data, i : eval(condition))
    return [ i for i in xrange(left,right) if func(data, i)]
```